# how to acess excel cell value and set it

Tags: c#

need  to open an excel sheet and then  go an to cell range  like  A 4, B5
**set A4= " India" and set  B5="Report name"**

in the  excel sheet i do not have any headers like.i have few data dump in excel sheet
above that data i need to write 2 value "India" and  "Report name " in the cell  range

**A4=" India" and set B5="Report name**

please  let me know  how  to  do it.

any help would be great, please let me know  how  to go  ahead here any code will help me

Comment: Possible Duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333313/using-c-sharp-to-read-write-from-excel-spreadsheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option is using [Microsoft's Excel API's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa188489.aspx) though it works through a COM layer and requires an Excel licence for each machine it's run on. [Here's a quick intro](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302084).

I've personally used [Gembox's spreadsheet libraries](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/overview) before and found them to be very well made ... btw, no, I don't work for them ;-) They do have a [free option](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/free-version) which might be ok to get started with, though it has a few limitations on number of rows etc. but the commercial version might be a good option if you do have some resources behind the project as it might well be the quicker route.